# when reading input stream gets few extra bytes before the wanted string

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

i have a server and a client.
i'm connecting the server from the clients and immediately sends a message,
then i want the server to send message to the clients but when i send the message to the clients.
the input stream of the server which is in the client's code, looks like this:

```
#$@ok
```

the "#$@" is bytes that is not my string which i have no idea what are doing there.

this is my client function which connects to the server sends data and waits for the the server to send:

```
public void connectToServer(String ip, int port, String boardSize) throws UnknownHostException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    server = new Socket(ip, port);
    serverInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream()));
    PrintWriter serverOutput = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(server.getOutputStream()));
    ObjectOutputStream player1OutputData = new ObjectOutputStream(player1.getOutputStream());
    ObjectOutputStream player2OutputData = new ObjectOutputStream(player2.getOutputStream());

    serverOutput.println(boardSize);
    serverOutput.flush();
    String isGameStarted = serverInput.readLine();
    if(isGameStarted.equals("ok")) {
        ...
    }
}
```

and this is my server code which send the "ok" string:

```
        BufferedReader player1Input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(player1.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader player2Input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(player2.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter player1Output = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(player1.getOutputStream()));
        PrintWriter player2Output = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(player2.getOutputStream()));
        String gameStarted = "ok"

        player1Output.println(gameStarted);
        player1Output.flush();

        player2Output.println(gameStarted);
        player2Output.flush();

        System.out.println("message sent to clients: \"" + gameStarted  + "\"");

        player1OutputData.writeObject(gameBoard);
        player2OutputData.writeObject(gameBoard);
```

i didnt send any garbage data, why would it be there?
and what should i do to clean it up?
thanks!

**EDIT**: ok so i think i know when this is happening,
after i send "ok" i want to send a string matrix to the clients as well, so when i do that for some reason the "String isGameStarted = serverInput.readLine();"
line isn't getting the "ok" string, it is getting the array, and after i remove those lines(where i send the array), the garbage bytes remain there, i don't know why.

Comment: Difficult to say much, since `"mystring"` doesn't look like what you are sending anywhere.  Is that the `boardSize`?  When you say "the input stream looks like", are you talking the client's input stream, or the server's input stream?  Also, you have an `ObjectInputStream` in the client, but I see no creation of an `ObjectOutputStream` in the server.  You've read in `garbage` ... is that what is printing the "`#$@"`?  Finally, mixing `ObjectInputStream` and `InputStreamReader` on the same `server.getInputStream()` is asking for problems.  Create your stream as text, or objects, not both.

Comment: mystring is the "ok" im sending from the server, im sorry if i confused you.
the server input stream in the client's code contains a little garbage bytes before the "ok" string that i sent from the server
the ObjectInputStream is not related to the problem, i do send from the server an array and i want to get it in the client after i get the ok, the problem is like i said is in this line: "String isGameStarted = serverInput.readLine();" i didnt get here the "ok" i got "#$@ok"
i hope i cleared my self now :)

Comment: What is `player1`?

Comment: player1 is a client which i send to an "ok" string

Comment: You aren't logging what you're actually sending. There is no proof here that you aren't sending the junk.

Comment: what do you mean? "player1Output.println("ok");" this is the line where i send to the client the string, i dont send anything else but that.

Comment: You are printing what you allege is '"ok'" but clearly isn't, as a string literal, but you are logging the content of `gameStarted`. Clearly the matrix you now admit you are also sending is getting mixed up with the OKs.

Comment: yeah i changed it because i didnt paste here the gameStarted value,
i will change it now.
but still, this isn't the cause for the problem, please read my edit, thanks.

Comment: why is it so clear that they are getting mixed up ? 
it should be like: 1.server sends ok 2. clients get the ok 3. server sends the matrix 4. clients get the matrix

Comment: Why does your client code have `server`, `player1` and `player2` `getOutputStream()` calls?  Seems like at least one too many output streams.